# Exclude records that have specific value in joined table

Tags: mysql

```
ID      Colour           colour     Size
== Table 1 ==          ====   Table 2   ====
1.**  |  **Blue**     **Blue**    |     Big
2.    |    Red        **Blue**    |     Average
3.    |    Yellow     **Blue**    |   **Small**
4.    |    Orange       Purple    |     Big
5.    |    Pink         Grey      |     Average
6.    |    Green        Red       |     Big
```

Hi,

In the above table, in MySQL I need to return any ID that does not have a value of 'Small'. I am having trouble as if I tell it to not include 'Size' as 'Small' is still returns 'ID 1.' because the colour blue still has a value that is allowed (Big + Average).
I need a statement that will ignore Blue entirely (therefore not return ID 1.) because it has small linked to a colour in table 2.

Apologies if ive made this more confusing than it is. Im new to cross referencing two tables.

```
Select Table1.ID
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.colour = Table2.colour
and table2.size != Small
```

I think I need an inner join query, or Not Exist statement?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for inner joins. You had syntax errors though:

```
Select Table1.ID
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.colour = Table2.colour
and NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT T3.size FROM Table2 T3 WHERE 
  T3.size = 'Small' AND T3.colour = Table1.colour);
```

Comment: As blue still has values that '<> 'Small' such as 'average' and 'big', it still returned ID1

Comment: Yes that worked, I had to tweak some previous code that was causing it to loop and still return 'Small' but yours worked perfect, Thank you.

Comment: I tried, I don't have the required reputation. I think I'll sign up from now on.